# Ext Js communication Failure

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs in my application with J2ee framework. it happens that after working for sometime on my application I get a communication failure. There is no server side error.I have to delete cookies from my browser (i use IE most of the times) and then restart my browser and everything works fine. CAN I GET RID OF THIS PROBLEM?

Comment: How do you connect to the server? thru Direct? any sample code?

Comment: I would definitely look into how you are handling sessions (including DB sessions) in your code.  I suppose it's possible that this is a connection pool issue if it stops working after a certain number of transactions or time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the specific error. For a while, I was getting a 502 error. This turned out to be a concurrency problem - I was firing off a datastore load then immediately doing a refresh of my control. This error mostly showed up under IE6, less so on other IEs and never on FF.